# Creating a subset from a dataframe based on a condition from another array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numeric np array which I want to use that as a condition/filter over a column number 4 of a dataframe (df) to extract a subset of dataframe (sale_data_sub). However, I am getting an empty sale_data_sub (with just the name of all the columns and no rows) as a result of the code

```
     sale_data_sub = df.loc[df[4].isin(sale_condition_arr)].values
```

sale_condition_arr is a numpy array

df is the original dataframe with 100 columns

sale_data_subset is the desired sub_dataframe

Sorry that I didn't include a working sample.

Comment: what is the column number 4 name ? just 4 ?

Comment: @khaledkoubaa yes

Comment: what you get when you do ```df.columns``` ?

Comment: @khaledkoubaa RangeIndex(start=0, stop=100, step=1)

Comment: RangeIndex ?!!, what you get when you do ```isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)``` ?

Comment: @khaledkoubaa True

Comment: ok, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that your df dataframe don't have headers assigned.
try:

```
#give your dataframe a header:
df = df.set_axis([str(i) for i in list(range(len(df.columns)))], axis='columns')

#then proceed to your usual work with df:
sale_data_sub = df.loc[df["4"].isin(sale_condition_arr)].values #be careful, it's df["4"] not df[4]
```

Comment: Tried that but still empty sub-dataframe, with 0 to 100 as the column names.

Comment: normally , how many columns you have ?

Comment: I have 100 columns in my original dataframe names 1 to 100

Comment: initially, before you do ```.set_axis```, columns are from 1 to 100 ? first one is 1 and the one you want to work with is 4?

Comment: 0 to 100, and the one I need to apply condition according to on it, is column 4